# Join two points with a loop in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Given the coordinates of two points, how to join two points not using a straight or bended line but a loop?

Here is an example:

[image: loop]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Add an intermediate point (below it is `(A)+(1,0.5)`), and connect it to `(A)` and `(B)` by curved lines.
- The first example uses `to[out=a,in=b]`, where `a` gives the angle at which the line leaves the first node and `b` the angle at which the line arrives at the second node.
- The second example uses `.. controls +(a:x) and +(b:y) ..`. `a` and `b` have the same meaning as above. `x` and `y` control how 'strong' the given angle is. The bigger the value, the longer the line tries to obey the angle.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[on grid]
  \node (A) {A};
  \node[right=2 of A] (B) {B};
  \draw (A) to[in=0,out=0] +(1,0.5) to[in=180,out=180] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[on grid]
  \node (A) {A};
  \node[right=2 of A] (B) {B};
  \draw (A) .. controls +(0:1) and +(0:1) .. +(1,0.5)
            .. controls +(180:1) and +(180:1) .. (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

With two intermediate points, and asymmetric 'strength'.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[on grid,baseline=(A)]
  \node (A) {A};
  \node[right=2 of A] (B) {B};
  \draw (A) .. controls +(0:1) and +(-90:0.3) .. +(1.3,0.5)
            .. controls +(90:0.3) and +(90:0.3) .. +(0.7,0.5)
            .. controls +(-90:0.3) and +(180:1) .. (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[on grid,baseline=(A)]
  \node (A) {A};
  \node[right=2 of A] (B) {B};
  \draw (A) .. controls +(0:0.8) and +(-90:0.6) .. +(1.3,0.5)
            .. controls +(90:0.3) and +(90:0.3) .. +(0.7,0.5)
            .. controls +(-90:1) and +(180:1) .. (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```